# SQL Server, count multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table made like this:

```
Col1       Col2         Col3
____________________________
A          AA           AAA
A          AA           AAA
A          AA           BBB
B          BB           BBB
B          AA           CCC
```

What do i need is to count how many rows have the same combination of Col1 and Col2, like this:

```
Count     Col1       Col2 
_________________________
3         A          AA  
1         B          BB 
1         B          AA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group by the columns and count the results:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [COUNT], COL1, COL2
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY COL1, COL2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Count, COL1, COL2
FROM TableName
GROUP BY COL1, COL2
```

Result:

```
COUNT   COL1    COL2
3       A       AA
1       B       AA
1       B       BB
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3606b/1).

`COUNT` returns the number of items in a group. Read more [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175997.aspx).